# mat-table sorting in Angular 8 is working differently, uppercase, lowercase are sorting differently along with numbers and null values

Tags: angular, sorting, mat-table

I have implemented generic data table using mat table. All things are working perfectly except sorting.
When data contains upper and lower case words then sorting does separate sorting for lower, upper cases, numbers and nulls. I tried all things, I think something is missing I could not figured it out.
Please check the code below. Appreciate your help.

Package dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "msal": "^1.3.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  }
```

data-table.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of Columns" matColumnDef="{{column.ColumnName}}">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'lightgray','text-align':'left!important'}" ><b><u>{{column.DisplayText}}</u></b></mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let DataSet" style="word-wrap: break-word!important;display: table-cell;padding-left:0px!important;padding-right:0px!important;text-align:left!important;" >
      <ng-container *ngIf="column.ColumnName == 'Edit' || column.ColumnName == 'Delete'; then EditDelete; else Normal">
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #Normal>
        <span class="mobile-label">{{column.DisplayText}}:</span>
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.Pipe || column.Pipe != ''; then SelectPipe; else NoPipe">
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #SelectPipe>
          <div style="word-wrap: break-word!important;text-align:left!important">{{DataSet[column.ColumnName]+'' | dynamicPipe: column.Pipe : column.PipeArgs}}</div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #NoPipe> <div style="word-wrap: break-word!important;text-align:left!important">{{DataSet[column.ColumnName]}}</div></ng-template>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #EditDelete>
        <span class="mobile-label" *ngIf="column.ColumnName == 'Edit'">{{column.DisplayText}}:</span>
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.DisplayText=='View'; then ViewDisplay; else EditDisplay">
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #ViewDisplay>
          <div style="cursor:pointer!important;" *ngIf="column.ColumnName == 'Edit'"><i class="fas fa-binoculars  text-success"  (click)="onEdit(DataSet[IdColumnName])"></i></div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #EditDisplay>
          <div style="cursor:pointer!important;" *ngIf="column.ColumnName == 'Edit'"><i class="fas fa-edit text-success" (click)="onEdit(DataSet[IdColumnName])"></i></div>
        </ng-template>
        <span class="mobile-label" *ngIf="column.ColumnName == 'Delete'">{{column.DisplayText}}:</span>
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.DisplayText=='Void'; then VoidDisplay; else DeleteDisplay">
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #VoidDisplay>
          <div style="cursor:pointer!important;" *ngIf="column.ColumnName == 'Delete'"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle  text-danger" (click)="onDelete(DataSet[IdColumnName], DataSet[MessageColumn])"></i></div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #DeleteDisplay>
          <div style="cursor:pointer!important;" *ngIf="column.ColumnName == 'Delete'"><i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger" (click)="onDelete(DataSet[IdColumnName], DataSet[MessageColumn])"></i></div>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="ColumnNames;sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ColumnNames;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

data-table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {

  constructor() {
    if (this.DataSet) { this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.DataSet); }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.DataSet) {
      this.dataSource.data = this.DataSet;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.DataSet) {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.DataSet) {
      this.ColumnNames = this.Columns.map(c => c.ColumnName);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.DataSet);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  //Input parameters from parent components
  @Input() public MessageColumn;
  @Input() public IdColumnName;
  @Input() public DataSet: any[];
  @Input() public Columns: DisplayColumns[];
  @Input() ColumnNames: string[];
  @Input() public DisplayAddButton: boolean = false;

  //Raising events 
  @Output() public EditEvent = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public DeleteEvent = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() public AddEvent = new EventEmitter();

  //Send Add event to the caller
  onAdd() {
    this.AddEvent.emit();
  }
  //Send edit event with Id to the caller
  onEdit(Id) {
    this.EditEvent.emit(Id);
  }
  //Send delete event with Id and Message value(this value is useful when caller to show which item name got deleted) to the caller
  data: any[];
  onDelete(Id, MessageValue) {
    this.data = [{ 'Id': Id, 'MessageValue': MessageValue }];
    this.DeleteEvent.emit(this.data);
  }

  //search in the table all column values
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}

export class DisplayColumns {
  ColumnName: string;
  DisplayText: string;
}

export class DisplayColumnsWithFormat {
  ColumnName: string;
  DisplayText: string;
  Pipe: object;
  PipeArgs:string[];
}
```

Calling data table in different component

sample.component.html

```
  <app-data-table [Columns]="columns" [DataSet]="dataSet"></app-data-table>
```

sample.component.ts

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

  columns: DisplayColumns[] = [
    { 'ColumnName': 'position', 'DisplayText': 'Position' },
    { 'ColumnName': 'name', 'DisplayText': 'Name' },
    { 'ColumnName': 'weight', 'DisplayText': 'Weight' },
    { 'ColumnName': 'symbol', 'DisplayText': 'Symbol' },
    { 'ColumnName': 'Edit', 'DisplayText': 'Edit' },
    { 'ColumnName': 'Delete', 'DisplayText': 'Delete' }
  ];

  dataSet = ELEMENT_DATA;
```

Result
[sorting lower case and upper case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgmOp.png)

Comment: Please try to minify your example code and if you can, give us a reproucible example to help you. If you can build some easy at stackblitz please do it.

Comment: Juan, I tried with stackblitz but getting lot of errors because of versioning changes, fixing those errors is another big task. The code is generic version of mat table, you can call the code from any component. I will post the code of calling in different components

Comment: Juan, did you check the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite method sortingDataAccessor .See details here : https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9205